# Why ActionListener on JButton does not work in Swing in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, swing, user-interface, events, actionlistener

I am learning Swing and Kotlin. I want to change text of the button. I made ActionListener on JButton, but when I compile Kotlin project, run by javaw.exe and click on the button, it does not change its text (but it works in Java!). I searched problem in Yandex and YouTube, but there are few of tutorials where there are no proofs that code is working. What is the problem? May be Kotlin is incompatible with Swing?

And yet another problem. When I run code, I see blank window. And when I change its size, then the button appeared. And in Java, and in Kotlin that problem exists. How to solve it?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.Color
import java.awt.*
fun main() {
    val frame = JFrame("Example")
    frame.defaultCloseOperation = WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
    frame.setSize(400, 300)
    frame.isVisible = true

    val button = JButton("Please click me");
    button.addActionListener {
        button.setText("10 + 20")
    }
    frame.add(button);
}
```

OpenJDK 21.0.2, Kotlin 1.9.23-release-779, Windows 10 64bit

*P. S.* Please don't dislike me, because I am beginner in Swing and Kotlin.

What did I done:

1. I changed from `text` to `setText`
2. I wrote `addActionListener`  by many methods:

   - `button.addActionListener {button.text = "10 + 20"}`
   - `button.addActionListener() {button.text = "10 + 20"}`
   - `button.addActionListener({button.text = "10 + 20"})`
3. I removed lambda-expression: from `button.addActionListener{`**`e ->`** `button.setText("10+20")}` to

   1. `button.addActionListener`**`{`**`button.setText("10+20") }`

Expected behavior: changing button's text to "10+20"

**EDIT**:

When I executed my code by java.exe, I got next message in console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics                
        at AwtrunKt.main$lambda$0(Awtrun.kt)                                                                         
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)                     
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)                 
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)              
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)                       
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)       
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)                                    
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)                               
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)                                         
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)                                         
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)                                    
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)                                    
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)                                        
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)                       
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)                        
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)                            
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)                                    
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)                                          
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)                                        
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)                                   
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)                                               
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)                                               
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)                          
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)                                                                                                              
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)                                                                                                              
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)                                               
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)                                               
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)                          
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)                                                                                                              
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)                                       
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)            
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)               
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)            
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)                        
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)                        
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)                                
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics                                          
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)                   
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)                
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)                                           
        ... 36 more
```

What is it?!

Comment: You don't have the Kotlin standard library in your classpath.  (This is nothing to do with Swing or AWT, or your code.)  Kotlin has a (fairly small) standard library of its own, which needs to be available when running Kotlin code.  If you run it with the `kotlin` command, then that adds it automatically; however, if you're running it with the `java` command, then you'll need to add it to your classpath manually.  (If you're running it from a .jar file, then you'll need to include the Kotlin stdlib class in there, or use a framework such as Spring which takes care of it for you.)